# samba dns_update error is telling me records already exists

Tags: linux, dns, samba, rocky-os

I'm attempting to setup up Samba4 ADDC on rocky-linux-8. After everything has been configured and installed and I check on the status of Samba it tells me that it's actively running yet at the end of the check I receive `dns_update` errors.

My samba AD seems to be running fine but I would like to know why these errors are occurring and if there is a way to resolve them

````
Apr 12 11:33:58 samba80Test samba[15265]:   /usr/local/samba/sbin/samba_dnsupdate: ERROR(runtime): Record already exists; record could not be added. zone[corp.fin-rec.com] name[_ldap._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.DomainDnsZones] [>
Apr 12 11:33:58 samba80Test samba[15265]: [2023/04/12 11:33:58.072095,  0] ../../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:355(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
Apr 12 11:33:58 samba80Test samba[15265]:   /usr/local/samba/sbin/samba_dnsupdate: ERROR(runtime): Record already exists; record could not be added. zone[corp.fin-rec.com] name[ForestDnsZones] [WERR_DNS_ERROR_RECORD_ALREADY_EXISTS] - (9>
Apr 12 11:33:58 samba80Test samba[15265]: [2023/04/12 11:33:58.072139,  0] ../../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:355(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
Apr 12 11:33:58 samba80Test samba[15265]:   /usr/local/samba/sbin/samba_dnsupdate: ERROR(runtime): Record already exists; record could not be added. zone[corp.fin-rec.com] name[_ldap._tcp.ForestDnsZones] [WERR_DNS_ERROR_RECORD_ALREADY_E>
Apr 12 11:33:58 samba80Test samba[15265]: [2023/04/12 11:33:58.072179,  0] ../../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:355(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
Apr 12 11:33:58 samba80Test samba[15265]:   /usr/local/samba/sbin/samba_dnsupdate: ERROR(runtime): Record already exists; record could not be added. zone[corp.fin-rec.com] name[_ldap._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.ForestDnsZones] [>
Apr 12 11:33:58 samba80Test samba[15265]: [2023/04/12 11:33:58.109904,  0] ../../source4/dsdb/dns/dns_update.c:86(dnsupdate_nameupdate_done)
Apr 12 11:33:58 samba80Test samba[15265]:   dnsupdate_nameupdate_done: Failed DNS update with exit code 29 ```
````

Comment: As this is not a programming question within the scope defined by the [help/on-topic], it is off topic for Stack Overflow. For general operating system or application support, you may be able to find help on [su] or [unix.se], but be sure to follow their content guidelines to ensure an on-topic question.

Answer (score 1):

It is just that `Samba` is trying to update the DNS records, but the records already exist.

You can first check that the DNS records that cause your error are OK with `/usr/local/samba/sbin/samba_dnsupdate --verbose --all-names`

if it need to be updated use this, as an example if you wanted to remove `ldap._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.DomainDnsZones` `samba-tool dns delete <your-dns-server-ip> corp.fin-rec.com _ldap._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.DomainDnsZones SRV <your-dc-ip>`

then we restart `systemctl restart samba`